# Chrome Devtools for all tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure whether I'm imagining this or not, but I seem to remember there being a way to open a devtools window that logs console output from all tabs. I thought it was `option` + `cmd` + `j`, but that seems to be the same as the normal devtools.

Am I insane, or is this a real thing that I've just forgotten how to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevTools tech writer here. This is not a real thing. There's a 1:1 mapping between a DevTools window and a tab.

You might be able to accomplish something like this via [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer).